# CSS opacity transitions for toggled hidden elements

Tags: html, css, transition, opacity, display

I'm having a lot of trouble with this particular transition, and this particular area of my website in general.

I am trying to transition the opacity of the "#desk" element, so when you click "My profile" it fades in. The parent element should begin hidden, so it only shows when "showme" is in focus. I'm aware that you cannot transition "display", though the tutorial I looked at was able to achieve both the hidden element and an opacity fade so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have been able to transition this by making some tweaks, but I lose the toggle show/hide aspect which I would like to keep. I'm also having trouble with the toggle itself, as it moves the other elements in the page when clicked.

If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it, even just a rough idea of where I'm going wrong if it turns out there's too much to go into.

```css
.darea {
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:10pt;
}

.dtitle {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  color:#535353;
  font-family:'Lato';
}

.text-cent {
  text-align:center;
}

.dtitle h2 {
  margin-bottom:0px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#57BC90;
}

.half-txt {
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:25px;
}

.member, .member .dimg {
  width:400px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.dposition {
  text-align:center;
}

.showme, a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.showme:focus + #desk {display:block;}

#desk {
  display:none;
}

#dtext {
  opacity:0;
}

.showme:focus ~ #dtext {opacity:1;}

.trans {
  -webkit-transition: all 10s;
-moz-transition: all 10s;
-o-transition: all 10s;
transition: all 10s;
}

.dposition {
  letter-spacing:2px;
  width:100%;
}

.dposition h5 {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#535353;
}

.dposition span {
  font-size:10px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="darea">
<div class="member">
  <div class="dimg">
  <img src="images/profile_1.png" alt="director1" height="200" width="200" class="img-responsive">
  </div>  

    <a href="#" class="showme">My Profile</a>
    <div id="desk">
      <p id="dtext"class="trans">Lorem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum.  
</p>
    </div>
      
    <div class="dposition">
      <h5>Lorem</h5>
      <span>Director &amp; Director</span>
    </div>
</div>

<!---Member 2-->


 <div class="member">
  <div class="dimg">
  <img src="images/profile_1.png" alt="director1" height="200" width="200" class="img-responsive">
  </div>  

    <a href="#" class="showme">My Profile</a>
    <div id="desk">
      <p>Lorem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum
</p>
    </div>
      
    <div class="dposition">
      <h5>Lorem</h5>
      <span>Director &amp; Director</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/v1fyvxyw/ ~ check this fiddle

```
.showme:focus + #desk {
opacity:1;
visibility:visible;
position:relative;
}

#desk {
  visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you. I should be able to work out the rest on my own so I appreciate the help.